# Usar timestamp com ou sem timezone no postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

## Usar timestamp com ou sem timezone no Postgres?

A aplicação Web será usada em países diferentes, por tanto terei de lidar com fuso horários diferentes. O sistema possui entrada de dados de vários objetos diferentes que possuem o dia e horário que o dado entrou e foi alterado no sistema. 
Isto serve para o supervisor olhar e verificar se foi feito dentro do horário de expediente ou fora.

#### Exemplo

Se um objeto é inserido no banco às 03:00 AM na Itália, a visualização deste mesmo objeto no Brasil também deve mostrar 03:00 AM.

Para complementar o contexto, o backend é em PHP, banco de dados Postgres e no front temos javascript e jQuery.

**Como devo guardar esta data no banco, com ou sem timestamp? *Por que?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A diferença entre ambos pode ser encontrada [na documentação oficial do PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) e pode ser resumida como se segue:

- Quando se associa o time zone ao valor do timestamp, esse valor será modificado de acordo com a hora local do cliente;
- Quando nenhum valor é associado usa-se o UTC (Tempo Universal Coordenado) como default.

Só haverá diferença real se o cliente (sua aplicação) tiver setado a sua timezone (`SET TIMEZONE TO 'America/Sao_Paulo' por exemplo`) e o campo estiver com `with timezone` (ou o valor foi especificado com um timezone específico)

Você pode rodar os exemplos e ver que a hora resultante é diferente para cada zone:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-08-24 17:45:42' AT TIME ZONE 'MST';
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-08-24 17:45:42' AT TIME ZONE 'Japan';
```

No seu caso, se não quer que haja diferença, use sem timezone.

Outras referências: [Difference between timestamps with/without timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876218/difference-between-timestamps-with-without-time-zone-in-postgresql)

Comment: Utilizando o exemplo que eu coloquei na pergunta, devo usar com ou sem timezone? Não ficou claro pra mim.

Comment: Eu comentei ao final, se você quer que o horário seja o mesmo independente do local use sem timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Se você **não quer** levar em consideração o timezone você deve utilizar **timestamp** (timestamp sem time zone). Do contrário, utilize **timestampz** (timestamp com time zone).

Leia mais: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170

Comment: Utilizando o exemplo que eu coloquei na pergunta, devo usar com ou sem timezone? Não ficou claro pra mim.