# Como salvar data (yyy-MM-dd) e hora (hh:mm:ss) no PostgreSQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, data

Preciso armazenar no banco de dados PostgreSQL a data e hora que determinado registro tenha sido alterado ou inserido, porém na hora de criar essa coluna fiquei em dúvida sobre qual formato escolher, `timestamp with time zone` | `timestamp without time zone` | `Date`, minha necessidade é que no banco eu possa salvar dessa forma a coluna `2017-09-18 09:12:00`, então qual devo escolher?

Comment: E porque você não armazena uma data em vez de armazenar uma *string*? Aí sempre que precisar você usa como quiser. Ou até armazenar o *timestamp* que sempre deve ir sozinho, não faz sentido usá-lo com mais alguma coisa. Sabe o que é um *timestamp*?

Comment: Pode ser, hoje o campo esta como `Date` porém é necessário armazenar a hora junto, dai não sei qual seria a opção correta para isso

Comment: [Usar timestamp com ou sem timezone no postgresql?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232003/91)

Comment: Tenho a impressão que essa resolve, né?

Comment: Resolve sim @bigown

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica @rray

Comment: @bigown, nesse caso eu fecho a minha pergunta?

Comment: Já fechei :) ...

Comment: @bigown, Só mais uma questão, eu selecionei `timestamp without time zone`, o que eu deveria colocar como comprimento para essa coluna?

Comment: Eu precisaria ver melhor isso.